# Erase all lines in a file AFTER some pattern, EXCLUDING the line containing the pattern

Tags: sed, text-processing

I have been looking everywhere but I could not find any solution to get `sed` to erase ALL lines
in a file AFTER a certain pattern EXCLUDING the line with the pattern.

I expected a simple variation of that one-liner `sed  '/pattern/,$d'` to work but to no avail.

Anyone ?

Comment: You can use `sed '/pattern/q'` ; it'll just stop processing after having printed the line matching the pattern, effectively omitting all the following lines in the output stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's promote @Aaron's comment into the answer it deserves:

> You can use `sed '/pattern/q'` ; it'll just stop processing after
> having printed the line matching the pattern, effectively omitting all
> the following lines in the output stream

So simple and yet, so hard to find.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a duplicate but couldn't find one and forgot to come back to add a real answer. You should be able to mark your own answer as accepted by the way.

Comment: Glad you could not find a duplicate because I have been doing quite a search. If you want the credits/karma for it, make an answer and I'll delete mine ;)

Comment: No that's alright, I'm already glad I could help and the karma increase will be more significant to your account than to mine, especially now that your question must be quite low in visibility given its age.